# Lotus 8.5.3 on ubuntu 13.04

Tags: 13.04

everybody!

Just can't install this app on 13.04 gnome edition due to the absence of libcupsys2 packet. When trying to install it - there is dependency on libkrb53. Instead of it I have libkrb5-3, but it cannot be removed.

There is quite enough information about this issue, but I still cant find any workaround.

Thnx!

Comment: Get it!

Libcupsys2 can be depackaged using dpkg-deb -x and in control file change dependency on libkrb53 to libkrb5-3. Make new .deb and install.

Comment: please,could you explain a bit better? which version of libcupsys2 do you have? where do you donwload? any repository?
I need to download the correct version but I don't have the deb in my repos. Thanks

Comment: http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/c/cupsys/libcupsys2_1.3.7-1ubuntu3.16_i386.deb

Answer (score 1):

Get it!

Libcupsys2 can be depackaged using dpkg-deb -x and in control

http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/c/cupsys/libcupsys2_1.3.7-1ubuntu3.16_i386.deb
Here it is. So, if you also have libkrb5-3 instead of libkrb53 needed in dependencies you do the following:
dpkg-deb -x libcupsys2_1.3.7-1ubuntu3.16_i386.deb common
dpkg-deb --control libcupsys2_1.3.7-1ubuntu3.16_i386.deb
cd DEBIAN
nano control

You need to replace libkrb53 with libkrb5-3 
save and exit
cd..
cp -r DEBIAN/ common/

dpkg -b common libcupsys2_1.3.7-1ubuntu3.16_i386.deb

That's all!

Comment: forgot about sudo apt-get -f install while installing the lotus itself

Comment: Could you write step by step instructions
install Lotus 8.5.3 on Ubuntu 13.04? Sincerely, Vladimir Sharov.

Comment: a long story. on which step you are expirirncing problems?